# Selenium: how to find element with with specific text without contains option

Tags: java, selenium

Please see this:

```
<option data-="OK" value="110">
My Text
</option>

<option data-="OK" value="111">
My Text 2
</option>
```

I want to find specific element, so i have try this:

```
option[contains(text(),'My Text')]
```

So i this case i found 2 `WebElements` while i want to find the one that i want, i also try this:

```
option[text()='My Text']
```

But in this case nothing found.

Any suggestions ?

Edit:

```
<optgroup label="some text">

</optgroup>
```

Comment: actually what do you want????? do you want `option` element or `optgroup` element or both of them or anything else... you question is not clear...please update your question which clearly understandable....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
option[normalize-space(text())='My Text']
```

Comment: OK, another one almost similar to my first question: in case i have inside this element label with some text: label="test" how can i get this element ?

Comment: Do you mean `label` with parent `option`?

Comment: `option[normalize-space(text())='My Text']/optgroup[@label="some text"]`

Comment: You mean this? or just `//optgroup[@label="some text"]` ?

Answer (score 0):

Is this a dropdown you are trying to select value from?

for drop-downs you can try,

```
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@YOUR-XPATH-HERE"));
Select se=new Select(element);
se.selectByIndex(0);
```

or

```
se.selectByVisibleText("My Text");
```

or

```
se.selectByValue("110");
```

Comment: Yes this Drop Down List but this not working with Select, i don't know why